# Can't paste the text from buffer to Chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, google-chrome-extension, copy-paste

Tried to make an extension with a textarea in popup. But something seems wrong cause I can't paste with `ctrl+v` shortcut copied before text in this textarea :(
What can be wrong with it? I already have some extensions installed and there is a possibility to paste the text in the textarea.

Maybe I need to do some magic to enable the paste?

Original, the textarea is created simply with `document.createElement('textarea')`, but I tried to create it in html code. The same result :(

Thank you for any assumption.

Comment: How do you paste it, programmatically? Please show some code.

Comment: no, trying just by the ctrl+v shortcut

Comment: code of textarea created - https://github.com/silentroach/twic/blob/master/src/js/popup/vcl/TweetEditor.js (just a simple document.createElement('textarea');)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

'Tis strange, but the rule

```
body > div {
  display: none;
  }
```

blocked the paste possibility. Don't know why O.o

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ChromE.Experimental.Clipboard API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.clipboard.html).

Comment: No, it was a problem with pasting by hand, not by a script. Solution is above your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this sample into to project and check it!!!

```
<body>
 <script>
    var createdElement = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(createdElement)
 </script> 
 </body>
```

There is no code problem. May be u can check up css or js for blocking Ctrl+v or paste in your project

like

```
function setClipBoardData(){
setInterval("window.clipboardData.setData('text','')",20);
}
<body onload="setClipBoardData();">
```

or some other methods. I hope its help to you ...